# How to make a discord bot read embed

Tags: discord.js

I have favorite discord bot game called "EPIC RPG" there's an event for players, so I wanted to make a bot that can announce the event with mention a specific role and adding some messages, how to fix this?

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'includes' of undefined
```

Here's my code

```
client.on('message', message => { 
  let embed = message.embeds[0];
  if (embed && embed.title.includes('Type ``join`` to join the arena!')) {  
   message.channel.send( "<@&757597420275368076>" +"\:moneybag:" + "**CATCH**" + "\:moneybag:" );
  }
})
```

https://prnt.sc/uuci4z

Comment: Change `if (embed && embed.title.includes())` to `if (embed && embed.title && embed.title.includes())`

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the following code ( for Discord.js V 13 ) :

```js
client.on('messageCreate', message => { 
  let embed = message.embeds[0];

  if (embed && embed.title?.includes('Type ``join`` to join the arena!')) {  
   message.channel.send( "<@&757597420275368076>" +"\:moneybag:" + "**CATCH**" + "\:moneybag:" );
  }
})
```